# Select radio buttons and perform action according to that

Tags: android

Hey guys I am thinking and trying over this problem since last 1 day. Searched a lot too but didnt get what I am exactly trying to do.

Ok let me tell you. I am trying to make an app, where the app will do some calculations based on the user inputs ( like in a calculator)

Firstly I have created a radio group with 2 radiobuttons.

Then after that 3 text boxes and then atlast a button.

Now what I am trying to implement with java is :

When the user select 1st radio button it should only display 2 text fields and when user selects 2nd radio button it should display 3 text fields.

And after that when the user inputs the required values and click on calculate the it should work according to that input values.

Means I will be having different formulas implemented by onclicklistener by button.

now let me explain whole thing by taking an example.

When 1st radio button is selected

Suppose you start an app and 1st radio button is selected. And 2 text fields are there. Now user inputs the values and click calculate and it should display the "Sum" of both numbers.

When 2nd radio button is selected

Now the user selects 2nd radio button and 3 text fields will be displayed. User enters value in all three and click calculate and it should display multiplication of all 3 numbers.

Guys I am trying to implement this thing since last 1 day or more but getting more and more confused of exactly what to do. How to hide the 3rd text field if 1st radio button is selected and how to implement 2 different formulas when calculate button is pressed depending on the radio button and text fields...Please help me.

Dont think that I am asking for code. I just need your suggesions and advices on how to implement this thing.

Please dont rate this question as negative as I'm posting this question after trying everything I could.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to enable/hide a text field.. try using the function called `.setEnabled()` .. here's an example of how it's used :

```
EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
edit.setEnabled(false);
```

as for checking if a radio button is checked or not .. simply use the`.isChecked()` function as fallows :

```
button1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbtnButton1);
if(button1.isChecked()) { /*do something*/ }
```

It'd be a lot more helpful to us if you'd posted some sort of code, no matter how simple it is in order to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the .setEnabled help I think it will solve 1 of my issues of hiding the 3rd EditText when 1st radio button is selected...Can you guide me more about how to execute the calculations...You can checkout my code above and you will get to know what exactly I am trying to do...Tried everything possible at my level...I'm all messed up...thanks

Comment: why don't you show me what you've tried .. it'd be a lot more easier for both of us.

Comment: Actually I have tried few things and going to try one last thing then if it wont work I will edit the post and will post the code...BTW thanks a lot for your help...Also I have many other issues too...So looking out for someone who can help me on and IM...